# Printing CSS on Firefox

Tags: html, css, laravel, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to create a CSS print sheet and here his my code :

**PHP (Laravel) :**

```
[...]
<div id="nameDiv">
  <h3> {{$project->name}} </h3>
  {{$project->description}}
  <h4>Homines deliciis  :</h4> {{$project->created_at->format('d/m/y')}}
  <h4>quemquam nec      :</h4> {{$project->scientist_leader->full_name}}
  <h3>A propos de ce projet | Impression </h3>
  {!! isset($project->comOverview) ? Blade::compileString($project->comOverview) !!}
  @foreach($iteration->innovations as $innovation)
    <h3> {{$innovation->name}} </h3>
    {!! html_entity_decode($innovation->description) !!}              
  @endforeach
```

**CSS file :**

```
div#nameDIV {
   display: inline-block;
   overflow: visible !important;
}
```

I've something like this :

[On Chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMjfg.png)
It works and I have multiple pages depending on the text.

[On Firefox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L134V.png)
Here it doesn't work: I have one page and the text is cut.

If someone has any idea.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Laravel version?

Comment: You use `nameDiv` as an id in your HTML, but `nameDIV` in your CSS (watch the case)

Comment: Laravel version : 5.2.45

Comment: I know it's because I've change the name for stack Overflow but in my code they have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different styles by default (user agent stylesheet). You need to override those styles with your css. Hope this is the reason.

Comment: I've try to do this :    html,
body {
    moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}                    but the text still cut.

Comment: @IntelCapols Did you try setting the margins of the body tag to 0 ?

Comment: Yes i try but it did nothing.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle link .?

Comment: You have that issue only while printing .?